# Does "learn by hard" mean the same thing as "learn by heart"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I know what the expression "learn by heart" means, but I have just discovered that there's also "learn by hard", and I was wondering if this expression was just misspelled or if it is really used, and if it has the same meaning of "learn by heart".

Specifically, the context was the following:

> You should know the definition of a vector space by hard.

Comment: I have never heard somebody say "learn by hard."

Comment: Native speaker in the United States.  I have never heard _"learn by hard"_ and I am not sure what it would mean.

Comment: @Xenomorph Did you **see** *learn by hard* wriitten down or did you think you **heard** *learn by hard*? As others have said, *learn by hard* is not an English expression.

Comment: Okay, well it was a mistake. ;)  Either way it is a mistake. I was curious if it was read or heard, because an answer could focus on one aspect or another.

Comment: Are you thinking of *learn the hard way*?

Comment: In the specific context given, it definitely should be "by heart".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a misspelling.

Comment: @DamkerngT. The asker hasn't made it completely clear whether this was heard or read ('misspelled' not withstanding), but since the alleged misspelling resulted in a real word that could plausibly be part of a real phrase this seems very on-topic. I found a few other forums where this same question was asked, apparently by different people, indicating that it's a question others may have.

Comment: A cursory web search would have revealed the answer to this.

Comment: I'm trying to help you to better research your questions in the future! No need to get defensive. :) If I just downvoted, you would not know why.

Comment: "Learn by hard" is reminds me of "Learning the hard way," which means by making mistakes instead of listening to others tell of their experiences.  "The zookeeper warned me not to poke the bear, but I did not listen and had to learn the hard way." It would never be phrased, "I learned by hard," though.

Comment: Language Log has coined the neologism you want for this sort of thing: "[eggcorn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggcorn)".

Comment: RE: _There's a lot of debate on the web if "learn by hard" is just a typo or a misspelling or not, that's why I asked._ Had you been more clear about that when you asked your question (perhaps even showing places where you've seen both, and even linked to one of these "debates"), then much of this discussion could have been averted. Instead, you only provided scant details your question, and therefore ended up clarifying in a long discussion beneath your question. This is exactly why we ask for [details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know about Xenomorph, but I read "A cursory web search would have revealed the answer to this" as pretty offensive. Yes we could use some more details, but I get really sick of people assuming that others are going to get the same results when attempting web searches, or that they will draw the same conclusions. *Especially* on ELL stack exchange. If one lacks the insight into the language to realize that this was likely misheard, are you really going to assume they can confidently interpret english-language forum arguments?

Comment: @DCShannon: It's not offensive, it's a basic fact. Offensive is getting the community to do your Google searches for you. Xenomorph seemed happy enough with this, although his/her final comment reply to me seems to have vanished unfortunately. It looks like J.R., a moderator, removed me when writing his comment effectively agreeing with me. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, @J.R. And to the OP native speakers do not consider *learn by hard* to be correct, no matter the context or whether read or heard. Therefore it doesn't seem so important to me whether it's a typo or a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, "learn by hard" is not a stock phrase in English, and it's not clear to native speakers what is meant.

I believe most who hear this will assume that either they misheard or the speaker misspoke, and that the intended phrase was "learn by heart". Depending on a speaker's accent and tone of voice and the listener's ear, 'hard' and 'heart' may sound extremely similar. 'Heart' is generally pronounced more like 'hart', and a 't' and a 'd' may be difficult to discern at the end of a word.

A Google search for the phrase "learn by hard" finds a few places where someone asks if this is a phrase and are told that "learn by heart" is meant, and a few other hits where it is part of a larger expression, such as "learn by hard work" or "learn by hard experience".

I would assume that either you misheard, or that someone is guilty of a typo.

Comment: @pazzo Is that a typo? "Learn by heard" doesn't make sense, either. "Hard" could be misheard for "heart" simply because in some accents (typically American ones), they sound very similar. What other reason could there be?

Comment: You mean they mishard. :P

Comment: @DavidRicherby as an American, I can say that I am unfamiliar with any American accent in which "heart" and "hard" could be confused.  I would suspect that this mistake is made by speakers of languages, like Dutch or German, where final voiced consonants are de-voiced (for example, German "Rat," meaning "counsel," and "Rad," meaning "wheel," are pronounced identically).  It is also possible that some people would fail to notice the difference in vowel length between American "hard" and "heart," that serves to distinguish the words when the final consonant is swallowed.

Comment: In a *different* context, though, it might be amusing wordplay for learning through hard experience. But definitely not stock, and certainly not in the quoted sentence.

Comment: @phoog In my (English) accent, "hard" and "heart" have identical vowel sounds and are distinguished by their terminal consonant. To anybody who's used to such an accent, an accent where the words have identical terminal consonants and are distinguished by their vowel sound is going to lead to mis-hearings.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's not so much that being used to an accent like yours that will make an accent like mine sound ambiguous; it is rather being unfamiliar with an accent like mine (it's possible to be familiar with both, that is).  I mainly wanted to point out that "sounding very similar" is very subjective.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would also add that the terminal consonants of "hard" and "heart" in most if not all American accents are decidedly *not* identical; they're just difficult to hear in some contexts or when spoken by some speakers.  I don't think anyone would be likely to mishear "hard knocks" as "heart knocks," even if many would miss the distinction between a "hard attack" and a "heart attack."

Comment: @phoog Your last comment is pretty much exactly what I was trying to say. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby you're welcome.  I just remembered an amusing incident when an American colleague of mine illustrated some difficult task by likening it to "herding cats"; two colleagues, one Dutch and the other Irish, heard "hurting cats"!

Comment: The English idiom that does use "hard" in reference to learning is:  **"learn (it) the hard way"**

Comment: Incidentally, in British English there is the idiom *to leam something off by heart*, which means the same things as *to learn something by heart.* Most Americans have never heard the version with *off* in it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably heard the "d" sound which misled you. The correct way to say it is: "I learned it by heart." It should not be shortened to anything else. Here's an example:

> Carol of the Bells is my favorite song. I loved it so much when I first heard it that I found the sheet music and learned it by heart when I was ten years old. Would you like to hear it?

There is also "know it by heart." Here's an example:

> The show is on Friday. We need to be ready for a dress rehearsal by Tuesday.
> Reply: We are ready now. We know it by heart.